# Best way to use returns to break from a loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, return, code-structure, function-definition

First of all, I'm not a native speaker, so please excuse me if there are grammatical errors. :)
I'm a real greenhorn and just started to learn programming - i choose Python 3 as my first language. So please be lenient :)
I already tried to find an answer by myself, but i wasn't successful.
What is the better or more correct "style". Is there maybe a difference on runtime. Thank You!

**Version 1:**

```
def newUsername(db):
    isUser = True
    while isUser:
        username = input('Set an username:...')
        if not username:
            pass
        elif username in db:
            print("This user already exists!")
        else:
            isUser = False
    return username
```

**Version 2:**

```
def newUsername(db):
    while True:
        username = input('Set an username:...')
        if not username:
            pass
        elif username in db:
            print("This user already exists!")
        else:
            return username
```

Comment: Since this is working code, you could post it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @o11c Sry, this is my first question i asked on stack-overflow. I will keep this in mind. BTW, can i still move the post, or is it too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version would be better.

This is better since you are not using an additional variable & also reducing an expression where you assign that variable with a value.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that too, but I wasn't sure.